# Question on basis change and endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations, machine-learning

This is a question given in the book Mathematics in Machine Learning.

[image]

I know how to solve the first part a. of the question, finding the kernel and image of the transformation matrix.
But I don't understand the second part of the question.

1. I'm not sure what the fact that it's an endomorphism tells me. I understand that endomorphism means that it is mapping to the same vector space and that it is linear. Does that mean it's mapping to a vector subspace of this vector space? (since it's not bijective) But the transformation matrix seems to say otherwise.
2. I don't understand what the "(with respect to standard basis in $\Bbb R^3$)" part means. Does it mean, the 2 basis sets we are mapping are wrt. to the standard basis, or that we are mapping the standard basis to a new basis? Or something else?
3. Finally I don't understand what the b. part is asking me to do. I don't understand the "with respect to the basis B" part either.

I've written the formation of a transformation matrix step by step, but I don't really understand what the question is even saying to infer anything.

I do know there is a formula for finding the transformation matrix when a basis is changed,

$A' = T^{−1}AS$ ($T$ and $S$ being the transformation matrices to map old basis with new).

But I don't know how I would apply it for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I'm not sure what the fact that it's an endomorphism tells me. I understand that endomorphism means that it is mapping to the same vector space and that it is linear. Does that mean it's mapping to a vector subspace of this vector space? (since it's not bijective) But the transformation matrix seems to say otherwise.

But in this example, $\Phi$ is bijective (since the rank is 3, and the kernel is $0$). It's exactly as you said: "endomorphism" just means a linear map from a vector space to itself (there is no assumption on whether or not it is bijective...it might be, but it might not).

> 2. I don't understand what the "(with respect to standard basis in R^3)" part means. Does it mean, the 2 basis sets we are mapping are wrt. to the standard basis, or that we are mapping the standard basis to a new basis? Or something else?

That's right: it means both the domain and range are written in the standard basis. If we call them
$$e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \quad e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad e_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} $$
then saying $A_\Phi$ represents $\Phi$ in the standard basis means
$$ \begin {align*} \Phi(e_1) &= e_1+e_2+e_3 \\ \Phi(e_2) &= e_1-e_2+e_3 \\ \Phi(e_3) &= e_3 \end{align*} $$
This is just obtained from looking at the columns of $A_\Phi$ (the coefficients of $e_1,e_2,e_3$ on the right-hand sides are the columns of the matrix).

> 3. Finally I don't understand what the b. part is asking me to do. I don't understand the "with respect to the basis B" part either.

Now, if we write the new basis as
$$ v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}, \quad v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} $$
Then the new matrix $\widetilde{A}_\Phi$ for $\Phi$ in the new basis is
$$ \widetilde{A}_\Phi = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{pmatrix} $$
where these coefficients satisfy
$$ \begin{align*}
\Phi(v_1) &= a_{11}v_1 + a_{21}v_2 + a_{31}v_3 \\
\Phi(v_2) &= a_{12}v_1 + a_{22}v_2 + a_{32} v_3 \\
\Phi(v_3) &= a_{13}v_1 + a_{23}v_2 + a_{33}v_3
\end {align*}
$$

So part $(b)$ is asking you to find these coefficients $a_{ij}$ of this matrix $\widetilde{A}_\Phi$.

The formula you gave is the correct one: $\widetilde{A}_\Phi = T^{-1} A_\Phi T$, where $T$ is the matrix whose columns are $v_1,v_2,v_3$:
$$ T = \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1\\1&2&0\\1&1&0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Until now I had thought that transformation mappings are used to map a vector of one basis set to another, essentially finding a vectors coefficients with respect to another basis. But here that does not seem to be the case with  AΦ. Does this mean the vector x (input vector) is being changed, as in the vector it is being mapped to (the output vector) is a different vector in the same space? If they both are coefficients wrt. standard basis then, they would be different vectors right?

Comment: Or if I still try to think in terms of basis vectors, I could say AΦ is mapping the particular basis set to the standard basis set

Comment: A matrix can be thought of in either of those two ways. In this context, the matrix $A_\Phi$ is thought of as a function, so it maps input vectors to (different) output vectors in the same vector space. On the other hand, the matrix $T$ in this example is just mapping a vector in one basis to its expression in another basis (the input and ouput of $T$ are the same vector, just in different bases).

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. One last thing I'd like to understand is, in the question it has been stated that AΦ is an endomorphism, but it's also bijective, hence it is an automorphism right? endomorphisms are linear but not bijective as far as I understand.

Comment: Endomorphisms are not necessarily bijective (they could be, but they don't have to be). Automorphisms are bijective endomorphisms. So you are correct, $A_\Phi$ is both an endomorphism and an automorphism.